# Scanning Suite for Windows

Tags: windows, scanning

I'm looking for a Scanning suite for my Windows 10 Home laptop, which I can use in conjunction with my Richo all-in-one.

This is a cheap all-in-one printer/scanner, and did not come with any specific software.

Some years back I used to have an HP all-in-one, and I really liked the functionality that came with its software.

I need the following functionality:

1. Ability to Scan Multiple Pages to one PDF
2. Ability to scan Images to different formats including PNG, JPEG & PDF
3. Ability for OCR and create a PDF with selectable Text.

I'm open to a free or even a paid software for this. What software would you recommend?

Comment: Most have a web interface - put it on your network and go to the IP in a browser and see what you get.  The one on my HP is somewhat clunky and is designed around very old browsers but it hits all of your points.

Answer (score 1):

NAPS2 is a free, open source Windows application (with experimental Linux support in beta). I believe it does everything you want it to, including scanning multiple pages into one PDF, exporting to PDF, JPEG, PNG, and TIFF (among other formats), and recognizing scanned text with an OCR feature. You can create scanning “profiles” which contain preset scanning settings (scanner, DPI, etc.) and can be chosen as needed.

The project website is https://www.naps2.com/, and documentation (if you need it) is available at https://www.naps2.com/support.html.

I would suggest downloading the beta version at this point, as it adds many improvements including the ability to check for updates (in the About box), and background OCR (with improved accuracy) as pages are scanned, resulting in much quicker saving. It can be downloaded at https://github.com/cyanfish/naps2/releases.

Comment: NAPS2 is excellent. Note that the release version now has all of the beta functions mentioned in this answer.  I'm not sure why, but NAPS2 development has stalled (no new releases for about 1.5 years as of 2020 December), but hopefully it will resume.